# Android: Unable to control the media player by sending the broadcast of key code

Tags: android, controls, media-player, broadcast

I have a remote device which sending command like PLAY , PAUSE etc to control the other android device. The receiver end will interpret the command and send a broadcast. I tried on my Galaxy S4 phone with 4.4.2 OS.

The player running on the controlled device does play the video which I have pause/stop.

Am I sending wrong broadcast ?

```
  @Override
    public void MediaPlayerAction(MPLAYERCOMMANDTYPE command) throws TException {

        long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Intent downIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null);
        KeyEvent downEvent = null;

        switch (command)
        {
            case PLAY:
                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0);
                System.out.println("PLAY SEND");
                break;
            case PAUSE:
                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE, 0);
                System.out.println("PAUSE SEND");
                break;
            case STOP:
                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP, 0);
                System.out.println("STOP SEND");
                break;
            case NEXT:
                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT, 0);
                break;
            case PREVIOUS:
                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS, 0);
                break;
            case PLAY_AMD_PAUSE:
                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0);
                break;
            case VOLUMN_UP:
//                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
//                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_, 0);
                break;
            case VOLUMN_DOWN:
//                downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime,
//                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0);
                break;
        }

        if (downEvent != null) {
            downIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, downEvent);
            App.getInstance().sendOrderedBroadcast(downIntent, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I have the same situation, the video does not respond to events, but the music does.